# Azure CDN - Custom hostname without www not working (NameCheap)

Tags: azure, dns, azure-cdn, namecheap

I'm trying to add a custom domain without www to Azure CDN services.

With www it's working perfectly. But without www I get an error (see first image)

[image: Azure CDN without www]

[image: Azure CDN with www]

[image]

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [RFC 1912 - Section 2,4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1912#section-2.4)

> A CNAME record is not allowed to coexist with any other data. In other
> words, if suzy.podunk.xx is an alias for sue.podunk.xx, you can't also
> have an MX record for suzy.podunk.edu, or an A record, or even a TXT
> record.

a `CNAME` can not be used at the apex (aka root) of a domain, so we can not use the `CNAME` records for the root domain as the custom domain in the CDN profile.

As a workaround, set up a CNAME `cdnverify.<yourdomain>` to `cdnverify.<endpoint>.azureedge.net`. Once all is verified and set up (including [SSL provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-custom-ssl?tabs=option-1-default-enable-https-with-a-cdn-managed-certificate#custom-domain-is-not-mapped-to-your-cdn-endpoint) if desired), delete the `CNAME` and use `ANAME` for the root record. Read [this blog](https://arlanblogs.alvarnet.com/adding-a-root-domain-to-azure-cdn-endpoint/) for more details.

The official recommended method is to create alias records in the Azure DNS. See [Point zone apex to Azure CDN endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-alias#point-zone-apex-to-azure-cdn-endpoints). If so, you will [delegate DNS zones with Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-domain-delegation) and [configure alias records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/tutorial-alias-pip) for your CDN profile.

### Edit

Please note that

> Pointing a zone apex to CDN endpoints for **Azure CDN from Akamai** is
> currently not supported.

You could change to use other CDN tiers if you're using Azure CDN from Akamai.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Tried following the blog, but still does not work. First link "Point zone Apex..." says this: "Pointing a zone apex to CDN endpoints for Azure CDN from Akamai is currently not supported.".

Comment: Yes, if you are using Azure CDN from Akamai, it's currently not supported yet. You could change to use other CDN tiers.

Comment: Another thing, If you have set up a CNAME `cdnverify.<yourdomain>` to `cdnverify.<endpoint>.azureedge.net`, you also should remove the CNAME `@` in the DNS zone. Once all is verified, you can delete the CNAME `cdnverify.<yourdomain>`, and add an A record for the root record. Could you please try this?